# Consumir WSDL desde angular 14+

Tags: angular, soap

Me dieron un WSDL para consumir y sacar información de ahí, de un método llamado `CargaFiltros`

Este es el WSDL
http://201.168.154.186/WebServices/wsinfo/Service1.svc?wsdl

Intenté hacerlo muy rústico para ver si funciona, pero no tuve éxito

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UdlService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getFilters(): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    })
    this.http.get('http://201.168.154.186/WebServices/Wsinfo/Service1.svc', { headers })
    .subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

<strike>De primera me esta regresando un error</strike>

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://201.168.154.186/WebServices/Wsinfo/Service1.svc' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Y tampoco tengo la más mínima idea de donde debería ir el parametro de `CargaFiltros` para dirigirme ahí

intenté con la librería [ngx-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap) y parecía funcionar, puesto que tiene un método llamado `.call()` donde si le pasa el método a consumir así como los posibles parámetros.

Desafortunadamente quedó sin mantenimiento y no es compatible con la versión de Angular que estoy trabajando.

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?

Comment: La respuesta corta: Tienes problema de CORS, así que no vas a poder consumir el WS desde angular

Comment: Hola. Este tipo de servicios tiene la bondad de "auto-documentarse" Con postman es posible cargar todos los entry point agregando el link. Una vez echo esto puedes revisar los encabezados correctos y  recrearlos en angular. SOAP requiere una estructura especifica tanto en los headers como el body. De esta manera puedes omitir el uso de la libreria.

Comment: El problema de cors al parecer es por que no le estas enviando la cabecera en el header mencionada en el error. Tienes que especificarla.

Comment: Ya resolví el tema del CORS, pero sigo sin la posibilidad de consumir una función específica del SOAP, tampoco enviarle parámetros

Comment: 2 consultas: 1) CargaFiltros pide un string como parámetro llamado hash_code, puedes brindarme uno valido para hacer pruebas ?? y 2) Un SOAP se comunica mediante XML, pero tu WS retorna a su vez un XML como respuesta (sería un XML dentro de un XML) que es lo más extraño que he visto desde que dejé los psicotrópicos. A ti te basta con tener el XML de respuesta o también quieres leerlo??

Comment: El hash_code es privado, una disculpa. Y si, la respuesta es retornada en XML. No está en la descripción del problema, pero si pudieramos parsearlo a JSON, estaría fabuloso, si no, con que la consulta sea exitosa, es más que suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La comunicación por SOAP no es más que una transferencia de XML's por POST estos XML contienen namespaces que hay que respetar, es una tecnología tan maravillosa que ahora ocupamos JSON y no miramos atrás. Además a través de header's indicamos la acción a realizar.

Las reglas son:

1. method: POST
2. Headers:

   2.1) "Content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

   2.2) "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService1/CargaFiltros"  (notar que este el método a llamar, para otros métodos habría que cambiarlo
3. Body en XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <CargaFiltros xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <hash_code>EL HASH CODE</hash_code>
      </CargaFiltros>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Desde angular 2 que no toco ese framework, así que no puedo entregar un ejemplo concreto. Pero puedo dar un código javascript que creo que es fácilmente migrable (incluso creo que podría funcionar directamente, ya que solo he usado funciones nativas)

Lo primero que hice es crear una clase `Code` donde la función toSoap me devuelve el Body

```
class Code {
    constructor(code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    toSoap() {
        return `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><CargaFiltros xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><hash_code>${this.code}</hash_code></CargaFiltros></s:Body></s:Envelope>`;
    }
}
```

Luego un fetch

```
let HasCode = new Code("3123123123");

fetch("http://201.168.154.186/WebServices/wsinfo/Service1.svc", {
    method: "POST",
    body: HasCode.toSoap(),
    headers: { "Content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService1/CargaFiltros" }
}).then(response => response.text())
.then(xml => {
        console.log(xml);
    }).catch (err => console.log(err));
```

Con esto obtenemos un string que tiene un formato XML

Ahora ¿Como leer ese XML?

Creo que no hay forma nativa de pasar un XML a un objeto, pero si es posible pasar un XML a un document y leero como se lee una página (usando getElementById, querySelector, etc). Esto usando [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```
let HasCode = new Code("3123123123");

fetch("http://201.168.154.186/WebServices/wsinfo/Service1.svc", {
    method: "POST",
    body: HasCode.toSoap(),
    headers: { "Content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService1/CargaFiltros" }
}).then(response => response.text())
.then(xml => {
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        console.info(xmlDoc.querySelector("NewDataSet"));
        console.info("=====================");
        console.info(xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("Error")[1].innerHTML);
    }).catch (err => console.log(err));
```

Comprobación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eres un crack hermano, excelente explicación y ejemplo. Funcionó con el hash correcto. Infinitas gracias

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob De nada, por 300 pts te habría dado un riñón también. Suerte con el proyecto!!!

Comment: ¿cómo es eso que a 300 puntos un riñón? ¿Usted toma frecuentemente? Es para una amigo :v hahahaha éxitos bro :D

Comment: jajajajaj te doy 600, es parte del scope de la pregunta. Gracias amigo!

Comment: @fredyfx Dejé de la bebida cuando vendí el otro riñón, recomendaciones del doctor.

Comment: HAHAHAAAAAA XD!!!! ok ok, no más comentarios antes que los moderadores invoquen al Mjolnir.